# memset an array to 1

Tags: c

I am trying to initialize a 2d array with some integer.If I initialize the array to 0 I am getting correct results but If I use some other integer I get some random values.

```
int main()
{
    int array[4][4];
    memset(array,1,sizeof(int)*16);
    printf("%d",array[1][2]); <---- Not set to 1
}
```

Comment: On Mac OS X, you can use memset_pattern4, memset_pattern8, or memset_pattern16 for this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`memset` set every byte of your array to `1` not every `int` element.

Use an initializer list with all values set to 1 or a loop statement to copy a value of `1` to all the elements.

Answer (score 7):

`memset` works on a byte-by-byte basis only.  Zeroing out the bits works in general because all integral zeros are generally all-zero-bits, so that grouping four all-zero-bit bytes into one all-zero-bits `int` still gives you zero.  For things that are not bytes, though, the simplest way to initialize all of them is just to explicitly initialize all of them.

Answer (score 5):

`memset` allows you to fill individual bytes as memory and you are trying to set integer values (maybe 4 or more bytes.) Your approach will only work on the number `0` and `-1` as these are both represented in binary as `00000000` or `11111111`.

The for loop isn't too much bother:

```
int main() {
    int i, val = 1, max = 4;
    int array[max][max];

    max = max * max;

    for(i = 0 i < max; i++) {
       array[i] = val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because **memset** works on byte and set every byte to 1.

```
memset(hash, 1, cnt);
```

So once read, the value it will show **16843009 = 0x01010101 = 1000000010000000100000001**
Not **0x00000001**
But if your requiremnt is only for bool or binary value then we can set using C99 standard for C library

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>        //Use C99 standard for C language which supports bool variables

int main()
{
    int i, cnt = 5;
    bool *hash = NULL;
    hash = malloc(cnt);

    memset(hash, 1, cnt);
    printf("Hello, World!\n");

    for(i=0; i<cnt; i++)
        printf("%d ", hash[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

Hello, World!
1 1 1 1 1