# why memset fill 0 in 2d array correctly but fail to fill 1 in that array?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, memory, memset

I try to fill a 2D array with 1 using memset.

```
int arr[3][3];
memset(arr,1,sizeof(arr));
Result :  
16843009 16843009 16843009   
16843009 16843009 16843009  
16843009 16843009 16843009
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761015/memset-an-array-to-1

Comment: Or just `man memset` and pay particular attention to the word ***bytes***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`memset` works on the byte level without regards to other step sizes. Your `int` is 4 bytes large and thus each of those bytes are set to `00000001b`, and therefore

```
00000001000000010000000100000001b = 16843009
```

Answer (score 1):

```
memset(arr,1,sizeof(arr));
```

Work on every byte. An int have four byte ( might change), so memset 1 on write on every byte which make int value to 16843009 ( in bianry 00000001000000010000000100000001).